# using purrr::map to apply to each value

Tags: r

There is a dataframe called iris, I have another tbl dataframe that has categories of Species.

```
df2
Column

setosa 
versicolor  
virginica
```

Now I use `iris[iris$Species == "setosa",]` to filter only setosa. But is there a way to use `purrr::map` function so that I do not have repeat the operation like below

`iris[iris$Species == "setosa",]`

`iris[iris$Species == "versicolor",]`

`iris[iris$Species == "virginica",]`

in other words, in single command I need to execute the filter with values in `df2$Column`

Comment: Why do you just do `split(iris, iris$Species)`?

Comment: This works. But can we do this using purrr:map funtion?

Comment: map iterates on each value of a column, so doing `map_df(df2, function(x) {iris[iris$species == x, ]})` would work. The better way would be to use `%in%`, so `iris[iris$Species %in% df2$Column, ]`.